# Return an array from multiple MongoDB trips to User Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am stuck on perhaps a general programming concept.

I have an array with two emails inside. I send this array to a static function, that loops through the array and finds the user in the database with that email.

However, at the moment with the callback setup I have, it returns me 2 objects (one per user, which is correct), however, I want this to be an array with the two objects inside.

Is there a way I can rewrite the database trip function, or can i just create an array somehow after I get the 2 objects? I've tried many different things.

Node MongoDB:

```
//I understand that the callback gets called twice, because it is inside a loop, But i have to have a loop to loop through the emails in the array. 

static spaceFindUsers = async ( friendsEmailArray, callback ) => {
        const db = getDb();
        friendsEmailArray.map( ( friendEmail ) => {
            db.collection( process.env.USERSCOLLECTION ).findOne( { email: friendEmail } ).then( friend => callback( friend ) ).catch( e => callback( e ) );
        } );
    };
```

Node.js result:

```
//Here I get 2 objects, I want them inside an array. 

User.spaceFindUsers( usersToAdd, ( friends ) => {
        console.log( friends );
    } );
```

Thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find, instead of findOne. Search for user's who's email address is contained within the input array.

Something like this:

```
static spaceFindUsers = async ( friendsEmailArray, callback ) => {
       const db = getDb();

        db.collection( process.env.USERSCOLLECTION )
            .find( { 
                 email: { 
                     $in: friendsEmailArray 
                 }
             })
             .then( friends => callback( friends ) )
             .catch( e => callback( e ) );

};
```

This way you'll make a single database call, and have an array of user records returned. The query is "saying" "Find me all user's who's email address is present IN($in) this array of email addresses".

**NOTE This assumes 'friendsEmailArray' is an array of strings.**

Also, a comment. Unsure why you're using async, this isn't needed if you're using a callback. Async methods will return a promise, this is not needed if you're using a callback, the callback denotes the async behaviour of the function.

Comment: No problem at all. Good luck :)